# RoboEarth installation problem

Tags: ros, rosmake, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to install RoboEarth on Ubuntu 12.04. So far, I followed this guide ros wiki with some minor modifications. I've done the following steps:

1.

```
rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/fuerte 'ros wiki source'
```

That gave me an error, so i just downloaded the roboearth.rosinstall file and used the path to that instead of the url.

2.
Added "`source ~/ros/setup.bash`" to the .bashrc

3.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ias-common ros-fuerte-perception-pcl ros-fuerte-opencv2 ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping ros-fuerte-client-rosjava-jni libsuitesparse-dev
```

...and what is important but not listed there

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob
```

4. 

```
rosmake roboearth
```

My problem is when I execute rosmake roboearth I get the following and cannot find a way to proceed any further:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['roboearth']                               
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/$user_name/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140219-162008
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['roboearth'] to:
['re_msgs', 're_ontology', 're_comm', 're_2dmap_extractor', 're_vision', 're_object_detector_gui', 're_object_recorder', 'ar_bounding_box', 're_kinect_object_detector', 're_srvs', 're_comm_core']
cannot find required resource: client_rosjava_jni
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob_addons
ROS path [2]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob
ROS path [3]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge
ROS path [4]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/stacks/ccny_vision
ROS path [5]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/stacks/roboearth
ROS path [6]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/vision_visp
ROS path [7]=/home/$user_name/fuerte_workspace/qr
ROS path [8]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [9]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [10]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131001/roboearth-installation-problem/) by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if things still work in fuerte -- you can at least try to install rosjava_jni using the .deb packages. It's in the package ros-fuerte-client-rosjava-jni. Alternatively, please try to install knowrob and its dependencies from source as described [here](http://www.knowrob.org/installation#installation_from_source).

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) on 2014-02-19**:
Thank you for your feedback, Moritz
However, I already have rosjava_jni installed. I checked it's there in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/client_rosjava_jni . When I try to rosmake knowrob according to the procedure you mentioned it gives me the same error: cannot find required resource: client_rosjava_jni

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-02-20**:
Have you re-loaded your bashrc? It's not listed above -- just open a new terminal and use that one, or type 'source ~/.bashrc'

**Comment by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) on 2014-02-23**:
Yes, I did. Currently it contains those 2 lines:
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
source /home/andriimatviienko/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
You also mentioned that those things might not work in fuerte. What version of ROS would you then recommend to use for roboEarth?

**Comment by [patrickl](https://answers.ros.org/users/12936/patrickl/) on 2014-03-07**:
you tried to install the package from source?

git clone https://github.com/gheorghelisca/rosjava_jni.git client_rosjava_jni

maybe this will work

**Comment by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) on 2014-03-07**:
That helped! Thank you! After installation I had to add the path to it manually by 'export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/client_rosjava_jni'. Afterwards I had the same problem with other packages from stacks folder and I manually added them to $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, what fixed the problem

**Comment by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) on 2014-03-07**:
After that I had the exact same problem as listed here http://answers.ros.org/question/68773/problem-compiling-re_comm/ and deleting UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java from ~/fuerte_workspace/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1 fixed the problem